# CSS | Overflow Scroll Issue

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Hello stackoverflow users,

Today I am using the overflow:scroll; property so I can hide all content but allow users to see it with a scroll bar.

See below picture:
[image]

You can see that the scroll bars appear even when not needed. Is there a way I can hide the scroll bar until needed, ie when there is actually overflowing content. It is a cosmetic issue for me as the scroll bar at the moment are naturally locked since there is no overflowing content, so why display it (I would prefer it not to be displayed just in case others have different opinions).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:scroll`

With `overflow:scroll` http://jsfiddle.net/0wekc9p2/1/

with `overflow:auto` http://jsfiddle.net/0wekc9p2/2/

Comment: I was going to, have to wait 2 mins before i can do this.

Comment: @TestyTosty okay forgot about the time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to set `overflow` property to `auto.` or remove the property altogether if it is not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS put this code within `body` tag

```
body {
    overflow:hidden
}
```